# Getting error on hive " Unable to retrieve URL for Hadoop Task logs. Does not contain a valid host:port authority: local"

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am getting this error which executing any query on hive which involves mapreduce.

> “ Unable to retrieve URL for Hadoop Task logs. Does not contain a valid host:port authority: local”

Comment: Something is wrong in your yarn-site and/or hive-site xml files

Comment: How did you install Hive? Manually?

Answer (score 0):

The reported Exceptions is seen in older versions of Hadoop (i.e. before `YARN`). Mostly you are using older versions of Hadoop.

The exception is seen when value of `mapred.job.tracker` parameter is set to "`local`" in `mapred-site.xml` instead it should be `<IP address of job tracker>:<port>`.